# How to load an entity in Symfony without special fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i want to load an entity in my Controller, but dont want that the entity contains all fields. I did that before with the Jms-Serializer, where you can use the Groups Annotations, to avoid loading special fields. But i there you have to serialize your object to json/xml etc. 
And i dont want it serialized, i just want that groups function. I searched this site and the internet, but didnt found any solution for my problem.

Hope that someone understand what i mean and got an idea :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying ot achieve, but from what I gather you probably want to take a look at [entity repositories](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)

If you post some code then it might be easier for people to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You can get an array result (without some fields) from your entitiy repository

Comment: if you want to load an entity, can we assume you want it as an object rather than a cutdown array? If it *is* an object, why not just ignore the props that you dont need? Or just create a method on the entity that returns the bits you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

1. Use **partial objects** (which will deliver objects where only specified attributes will be filled during hydration): http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html#partial-objects

This is dangerous and you should be extra careful, because it looks like a fully loaded entity from all perspectives. You have to know why a field is null - just because it's null or because it simply hasn't been filled during hydration.

2. Don't hydrate objects but query for an **array as hydration result** (by that again you can specify which array keys you would like to get back): http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#array-hydration

Use this for performance-sensitive queries where you need a lot of read-only data and complex joins. But be aware that you don't have any entities you can manage with Doctrine (e.g. updating, deleting etc.).

3. Use **DTO**s which are objects but non-Doctrine-managed entities, there again you can specify what you would like to get hydrated with the NEW syntax: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax

Basically the same advise as in 2) but this time you'll get objects. So you can use all your OOP wisdom.

4. Create your own **custom hydration mode** - there you can define on your own how entities should be hydrated: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes

Very advanced level. Only useful if you need a special hydration mode for several entities and really no other option delivers at performance and quality as you require it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial objects, but you should be careful. For example:

```
$q = $em->createQuery("select partial u.{id,name,otherField} from MyApp\Entity\User u");
```

You can read more here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html